# Closed enclosure thermal design the right way

Tags: power-supply, simulation, power-electronics, thermal, enclosure

I have a circuit board that works quite well (processor, screen, power supply).
It has been tested successfully for an open aluminium enclosure, but now it will need to fit a rugged 100% closed box.

I know that some people use simulations or excel tables to estimate the power, heat, volume, dissipation and element layout.

What would be the right way/process to design a such enclosure?

is there any software or other tool to optimise thermal performance?

I feel like we do it mostly by trial and error and experience only, and would like to have more elements to have success with less iterations.

Comment: What environment is this box designed to handle? Temperature? Altitude? Humidity? EMC? Vibration? Without knowing the context this is hard to answer.

Comment: its intended for industrial application , no need to get into much detail , im more interested on the methodology/tools than a quick specific solution